# C function not returning the right thing?

Tags: c, function

I have a function to convert the first 3 letters of the month into a number (Jan = 1, Feb = 2, etc).

```
   int convertDate(char date[3])
    {
        printf("%s", date);
        if(date == 'Ian')
            return 1;
        else
        if(date == 'Feb')
            return 2;
        else
        if(date == 'Mar')
            return 3;
        else
        if(date == 'Apr')
            return 4;
        else
        if(date == 'Mai')
            return 5;
        else
        if(date == 'Iun')
            return 6;
        else
        if(date == 'Iul')
            return 7;
        else
        if(date == 'Aug')
            return 8;
        else
        if(date == 'Sep')
            return 9;
        else
        if(date == 'Oct')
            return 10;
        else
        if(date == 'Noi')
            return 11;
        else
        if(date == 'Dec')
            return 12;
        else return 0;
    }
```

But, in main() when I use:

```
printf("%d", convertDate("Ian"));
```

it returns 0 instead of 1. Same for any other month. Any suggestion?

Comment: `date[3]` is too short for "Jan" or any 3-letter string. `date[4]` or greater is ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `strcmp()` when comparing `char*`.

`if (date == "Sep")` compares the base address of the `char*`.

Answer (score 2):

Since in C string variables are of type char *,  comparing strings like you do actually compares pointer adresses. Use `strcmp()` to compare strings instead.

Also, you could use `stricmp()` to do case insenstive string comparison.
Note, that you could implement your function also with a loop, defining all twelve fixed strings into an array (using strncmp() to ensure that we really only compare 3 characters)

```
int convertDate(char date[3])
{
    const char date_names[12][4] = { 
        "Ian", "Feb", "Mar", /* etc. */ };
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
    {
        if (strncmp(date_names[i], date, 3) == 0)
            return i+1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, strings are not of type `char*`.  A `char*` value may be a *pointer* to a string.  The string itself is a sequence of characters terminated by, and including, a null character, `'\0'`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but I did not say that strings are of type char *; I said that the variables used for strings are of type char *, thus indeed are pointers to the address where the first character of a string is stored.

Comment: `date[3]` is too short for "Jan" or any 3-letter string. `date[4]` or greater is ok.

Comment: Yes, the null terminator doesn´t fit within the three characters, but that´s why I use strncmp( , ,3). It depends a bit on different use cases of the function. Maybe you want to match "Ian 3" too. Anyway, did update the date_names to char[4].

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare array of characters using == operator. Look at [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/) function.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare strings like that except in very specific circumstances (don't worry about that).

You should use `strncmp`, "string compare". E.g.:

```
#include <string.h>
```

then

```
if(strncmp(date, "Ian", 3) == 0)
            return 1;
```

Note using `"` instead of `'`. Using `'` is entirely different, and can create a multi-byte int value on the stack, which you don't want.

Comment: `import` should be `#include`.  There's no point in using `strncmp` rather than `strcmp`.

Comment: Guess who's been writing too much Python... Only used strncmp because the OP knew it was 3 characters.

Comment: There's still no benefit in using `strncmp` rather than `strcmp`.  And it change the meaning of the code; consider `convertDate("Ianxyz")`.  (The parameter `date` is really a `char*`; the `3` is quietly ignored.)

Comment: If you read the first sentence of the question you'll find it says "the first three letters". To be honest it's not worth the hassle of defending my answer, it answered the question (and I started writing it when there were no answers).

Answer (score 1):

That shouldn't even compile.  You're comparing a `char*` value (`date`) to an `int` value (`'Ian'`).

This:

```
'Ian'
```

is not a string literal.  It's a multi-character character constant, and its value is implementation-defined.  It hardly ever makes sense to use it.

I'm guessing that the code you posted isn't the code you compiled.  That's why you should copy-and-paste the same code that you fed to the compiler into your question.

As others have said, when comparing strings, you need to use `strcmp()`, not `==` -- which means you can't use a `switch` statement.

You should also be aware that the parameter declaration

```
char date[3]
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
char *date
```

The `3` is quietly ignored, and if you call `dateCompare("Ianxyzfoobar")`, `date` will point to a string with a length of 12.

Comment: `date` is a pointer, comparing pointers to integers isn't an error. One should get a big fat warning, though.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yes, it's an error.  Except for the special case of a null pointer constant, applying the `==` operator to a pointer value and an integer value is a constraint violation.  (Like any such error, the standard only requires a diagnostic, which can be a non-fatal warning.)  See the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), section 6.5.9 paragraph 2.  The older C90 standard had the same rule.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yes -- and a cast would emphasize the fact that the comparison almost certainly wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: @Daniel: no, the cast would not make it legal: it would, however, prevent the compiler to let you know about the error.

Comment: @pmg: What do you mean?  `if (date == (char*)'Ian')` would be legal (but nonsensical), as would `if ((int)date == 'Ian')`.

Comment: @pmg Section 6.3.2.3, paragraph 5, "An integer may be converted to any pointer type." It's implementation defined and usually nonsensical, but legal.

Comment: I was referring to comparison between pointers and ints: `int k = <WHATEVER>; int *p = <SOMETHING>;` Now the comparison between `k` and `p` are all illegal, cast or no cast: `if (k == p)`; `if (k == (int)p)`; `if ((int*)k == p)`; `if ((void*)k == (void*)p)`; ...

Comment: @pmg: And the footnote says "The mapping functions for converting a pointer to an integer or an integer to a pointer are intended to
be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment."  Such conversions can make sense in rare system-specific circumstances, such as when a machine or OS defines specific numeric addresses to be meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

You are performing a pointer comparison, not a string comparison. Use `strcmp()`.